# How does Game Afoot interact with alternative ways of breaking objects?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

The perk description says: "Grants a 5% Haste Status Effect for X seconds after damaging a generator, or breaking a breakable wall or pallet [while chasing the Obsession]."

A few Killers have their own ways of breaking generators, walls or pallets, such as (but not limited to): any chainsaw Killer, Nemesis (Mutation level of 2+), Knight. Additionally any Killer can have an "alternative" way of breaking pallets with the effect of the perk Spirit Fury.

Do these alternative ways of breaking objects trigger the Game Afoot effect?

For example, if I am in chase with the Obsession as the Knight, and I send a guard to break a pallet, do I get the Haste effect? If it does work, does it work with **all** alternative break actions of all Killers (including Spirit Fury) or are there exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

According to the DBD wiki and from my testing **Game Afoot's** Haste Status Effect triggers **regardless of how a Pallet or a Wall gets broken**, be it through the Killer breaking it manually or **using their Power**, or by having **another Perk's effect break it.**
https://deadbydaylight.fandom.com/wiki/Game_Afoot

Comment: I have tried it as Knight and it did not work for me, with any of the three possible guards. I tried it yesterday and today after the patch (6.6.1) and I can not get the Haste effect to trigger. Regular kicks work, but a guard damaging a generator does not.

Comment: @Madjura In DbD, "breaking a breakable wall or pallet" means literally that, regardless of how it is done. However, "damaging a generator" specifically refers to kicking it and not using any powers or perks to do so. I know the wording is vague, but that behavior is consistent across all perks that require "damaging" a generator, such as Oppression, Dragon's Grip, or Nowhere to Hide. Otherwise perks such as Jolt or Hex: Ruin would activate a ton of other perks, which would be difficult to balance.

Comment: @MageXy I did more testing. From how I understand it the Knight power should activate Game Afoot when I break a pallet. Spirit Fury can trigger it, so there shouldn't be a requirement of using the kick action. But the Knight power does not trigger it. As far as I can tell the chase does not end when using the power (the chase music continued) and I was going after the obsession, before I sent out the guard to break the pallet as well as while the guard was breaking it.